# Chrome Extension doesn't expose web_accessible_resources file for creating Worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have an extension that injects a script to a page (through `activeTab` and `scriptings` APIs). The script also starts a Worker with the code provided by the extension and it's declared inside `web_accessible_resources`.

However, at the line of that code, I receive this error:

`new Worker(chrome.runtime.getURL("/worker.js"));`

> DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'chrome-extension://adlclchdicdgamgkekleoejhkeipcpmk/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'https://www.example.com'.
> at chrome-extension://adlclchdicdgamgkekleoejhkeipcpmk/inject.js:7:9

I have this code to confirm that the file is actually accessible:

```js
(async () => {
    try {
        const file = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("/worker.js"));
        const fileContent = await file.text();
        console.log("File loaded: " + fileContent);

        new Worker(chrome.runtime.getURL("/worker.js"));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
})();
```

`fetch` works (meaning the file is accessible) but `new Worker` does not.

I have also tried putting that code in the context of the web page (by inserting it using a script tag to the web page instead of executing it from content page context). The same problem happens.

Is this a bug of Chrome or did I do something wrong?

---

Full reproducible code here: https://github.com/datvm/ChromeExtWebAccessibleWorkerBug

**manifest.json**:

```json
{
    // ...
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "/worker.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**background.js**:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        files: ["/inject.js"]
    });
});
```

Comment: You use a cross-origin URL for the worker and that's not supported by the web platform. I guess the only solution is to read the contents of the script and make a blob: or data: URL. Another approach is to embed a chrome-extension:// iframe into the web page and use your workers freely inside.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah right my bad I didn't notice the error message is different from the inaccessible resource one. Your solution works and the library I am using (TesseractJS) even has that option built in.